# converting a date of particular format to ISO format

Tags: javascript

In material UI datepicker, it can accept a date only in a particular format. However, I need to convert them into iso format for some other operations to be performed on them.
Here is the format of the date.
2018-09-06
.I want the above to be converted into iso format.
Here is the code to generate date.

```
let today = new Date();
let dd = today.getDate();
let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd; // need to convert this to iso format .
```

Using the simple toISOString() took me nowhere.

Comment: No .I get today.toISOString is not a function.

Comment: Try this `new Date().toISOString();`.

Answer (score 4):

`today.toISOString()` should work fine. But `toISOString` method requires Date object not plain string of date.

```
const unformattedDate = new Date(yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd)
const formattedDate = unformattedDate.toISOString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**To convert a specific date in ISO format**

```
var d = new Date("2018-09-06");
var n = d.toISOString();
```

**To convert a today's date in ISO format**

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
```

Comment: FYI, OP is not trying to format the today's date. Look at the condition `if (dd < 10) {`